# Binding JavaFx Label to a Function Output which Changes According to Three Nodes Property

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to make a Label textProperty binds to a value from a function, which would take an array of Nodes (i.e., three Line Nodes), and then do some computation based on the Nodes' position property (i.e., startXProperty), so that whenever the positions of the Nodes are changed, the Label text will update accordingly.

This is my attempt:

```
Label label = new Label();

DoubleProperty myFunction(Line[] lines){

      DoubleProperty property= new SimpleDoubleProperty();

      // This is a sample computation, because the actual computation is much more complex. 
      // That's why I tried to avoid using the arithmetic methods provided by the Property class,
      // i.e., property().add().multiply()

      double computation = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lines[0].startXProperty().getValue() - lines[1].startXProperty().getValue());

      property.setValue(computation);

      return property;
}

label.textProperty().bind(myFunction(lines).asString());
```

And this approach doesn't work. I am looking a way to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: you need a Binding (which listens to the properties/observableValues it depends on)

Comment: see: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html

Comment: Also see [`Bindings.createDoubleBinding(Callable,Observable...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)).

Comment: @kleopatra: Thanks it works! I updated my revised code snippet. Please let me know is anywhere can have a better alternative. Thank you!

Comment: @Slaw: Thanks for providing the helper function! I searched a bit and it looks very convenient for a quick binding!

Comment: looks fine to me :) You might consider to post that as an answer, so that future reader find it more easily

Comment: @kleopatra: That's also a good idea :-) Moved!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: Solved**

Thanks to the answers provided in the comment, I changed the function to return a `DoubleBinding` and bind the `label` to it, and then it works!

```
Label label = new Label();

DoubleBinding myFunction(Line[] lines){

      DoubleProperty line_StartX[] = new DoubleProperty[lines.length];
      DoubleProperty line_EndX[] = new DoubleProperty[lines.length];
      DoubleProperty line_StartY[] = new DoubleProperty[lines.length];
      DoubleProperty line_EndY[] = new DoubleProperty[lines.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          line_StartX[i] = lines[i].startXProperty();
          line_EndX[i] = lines[i].endXProperty();
          line_StartY[i] = lines[i].startYProperty();
          line_EndY[i] = lines[i].endYProperty();
      }

      DoubleBinding distBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
        {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
                  super.bind(line_StartX[i]);
                  super.bind(line_EndX[i]);
                  super.bind(line_StartY[i]);
                  super.bind(line_EndY[i]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lines_StartX[0].getValue() - lines_StartX[1].getValue(),2));
            return a;
        }
      };

      return distBinding;
}

label.textProperty().bind(myFunction(lines).asString());
```

It acts as expected now! Just one last question, when using `super.bind(prop1, prop2, prop3)`, is there any easier way to add whole bunch of elements in an array at once?

Comment: If you're using `javafx.scene.shape.Line`, why not simply use the properties of those `Line`s directly? Also, you don't appear to be declaring `line_StartX` and `line_EndX` (or the corresponding `Y`) fields properly—the left side says the fields are arrays but the right side isn't declaring an array.

Comment: @Slaw: Good catch, thanks! It should be array on the right handed side as well. Corrected! The reason why I used an array instead of directly retrieving from properties is because in my actual implementation these lines have different priority, which is specified somewhere in the function, so the [0] position in each array would keep changing depending on which lines in chosen.

Comment: Assuming I understand your requirements correctly, I don't believe your code will work like you want. When you swap elements in `lines` around it won't affect the various `DoubleProperty` arrays. Unless that's desired? Also, `lines_startX[0] - lines_StartX[1]` is not valid—it's trying to subtract a `DoubleProperty` from a `DoubleProperty`. I suspect you meant to subtract the values of those properties?

Comment: Also, should the binding be invalidated when the `Line`s get moved around?

Comment: @Slaw: Thanks! I've corrected the .getValue() in the code. So for the lines, in my implementation I didn't change the order in lines[], but my function has an additional argument specify which `line` in `lines` is the target element, and such X and Y properties will be placed in the [0] position in all my Property lists (i.e., StartX[], EndX[], StartY[], EndY[] etc.), and then I would use StartX[0], StartY[0], EndX[0], and EndY[0] to compute.

Comment: oho didnt notice before: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: will do!